Strange resistor in battery charger
I've opened drone battery to take a look at built-in charger. The schematic based on LTC4054 is straightforward, except for one part. There seems to be 2 Ohm resistor (30Y) connected in series with capacitor between battery terminals. Also, it measures 1.8 Ohm, which is way beyond 1% tolerance of EIA-96.

Any ideas what it is there for?

maybe you're looking at the  component upside down

@jsotola The component is indeed labeled 30Y. The manufacturer is Yageo.

@Colin how did you get manufacturer from that? AFAIK "30Y" is standard EIA-96 for 1% 2 Ohm. I could be wrong, of course. Unless it is not a resistor at all.


There seems to be 2 Ohm resistor (30Y) connected in series with capacitor between battery terminals.

The purpose of the resistor is clearly explained in the datasheet:

For some LDO designs, since the output capacitor and its ESR bring a zero to the control loop, it can be crucial for stability. MLCCs have really low ESR so it's sometimes required to add a series resistor.


Also, it measures 1.8 Ohm, which is way beyond 1% tolerance of EIA-96.

Maybe you should measure the resistor whilst not in the circuit i.e. remove it and measure. Also make sure your ohmmeter or whatever you are using is accurate enough in that range.

Wow, I read through the datasheet four times and missed that. But... the charger is built-in, the battery leads permanently soldered to the PCB. Why would they add unnecessary components? Also, since one end of the resistor is connected to capacitor I don't think removing it from circuit would change anything. The multimeter, on the other hand, could be off for sure.

@Maple It might be copied from the data sheet without thinking. Or, it might be needed for stability. It certainly does not hurt to be there if it is not needed.

@Maple the charger is built-in, the battery leads permanently soldered to the PCB. Well, we can't know of course. Could be just they might have done blindly what datasheet says, as Justme pointed out. Or because if the wires are long they may introduce inductance therefore may be problematic for stability. Who knows? Also, since one end of the resistor is connected to capacitor I don't think removing it from circuit would change anything. The multimeter, true but MLCCs usually fail short so unless you are sure the capacitor is good it's still better to remove the resistor for measurement.

Well, whether they just followed the datasheet or added it consciously this answer explains its purpose. Still weird, though. I am not good with analog circuits and this is the first time I stumbled upon low ESR being described as bad thing. Always thought the lower the better.
